# Netlify Redirect not working in my app with React Hooks

Tags: react-hooks, netlify

Hi i try connect my page in netlify  with a service  external but i dont now how configurate _redirects  I put this:

```
/api/*  http://www.webservice.com/:splat  200
```

And my app get webservice and put these url  https://myapp.netlify.app/api/products

i want that put http://www.webservice.com/api/products

my _redirects is in public folder , my app is developer in react-hooks with webpack

plese someone cant help me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in your `netlify.toml` file:

```
[[redirects]]
   from = "/api/*"
   to = "http://www.webservice.com/api/:splat"
   status = 200
```

Then browse to `https://myapp.netlify.app/api/products` and it'll show you the page at `http://www.webservice.com/api/products`.